# Worklight.home environment variable not getting set

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-security

We installed the Worklight v6.1 Server on Tomcat. We now have an issue deploying the wlapp application file from the Worklight Console. I'm 80% sure this problem has to do with permissions.  The error, when trying to deploy the wlapp, is:

Worklight adapters will fail to deploy because directory '/worklight.home/worklight/data/export/adapters' could not be created. Restart the Worklight Server after fixing the problem. [project worklight]

The issue is that worklight.home isn't a physical directory, but should be an environment variable.  We don't know the value of that environment variable or where it gets set.

Answer (score 1):

The worklight server first try to build the adapter folder based on "javax.servlet.context.tempdir" property, that's mean the application server temp directory.

If that does not work,then the worklight server try to use System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/worklight.home/" + servletContext.getContextPath().

You can try setting the user.dir property if is not set yet.